# Advanced Java IDE Advice

Tags: java, ide

Is there any Java IDE that allows me see the bytecode, what is going on the stack when i keep stepping into? Something similar what i've seen in visual (disassembly, memory, registers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about something like this:

http://www.drgarbage.com/bytecode-visualizer.html